# Am I supposed to copy bootstrap folder to each new project?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This may be a stupid question, but I've downloaded Bootstrap 3 to make a new website.

Am I supposed to / Is the best practice to copy the entire Bootstrap folder into my New Website folder? And then this would be the easiest way to upload the server eventually? And do this for every new project?

Or am I supposed to just leave one copy in the Bootstrap 3 folder and reference it with my code?

I looked everywhere for this and can't seem to find a good answer, maybe this is just obvious to everyone. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can very well use the [**CDN**](http://bootstrapcdn.com) (Content Delivery Network) to serve the Bootstrap files.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Including the above will eliminate your issue to add the bootstrap files to every folder. Moreover, you are not supposed to add it in every folder. Say if you have a site as `http://example.com/`, you need to create two directories, namely `js` and `css` and add the files there, and link this way throughout the site structure:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Notice the `/` at the starting of the URL, which says this is a **relative to `domain`** URL. You need to use the above HTML to add the bootstrap content to all the pages, if you are using a template (that has headers and loads it on all the pages).

Comment: or link once from your template page that all other pages inherit from.

Comment: So I would add the above CDN code to obviate the local links? Or should I leave the local links in there as well?  

And, I guess I also meant this for what I'm supposed to do on my computer when I'm making the website - would the index.html need to be in the bootstrap folder?

Comment: You just need the CDN links alone, if you always have. You don't need a bootstrap folder in your project if it is an online project. Save some space buddy. `:)`